# Using Highchart with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, highcharts

I used Highchart with Django

Here is my value of temperature of a javascript object .

[42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 25.9, 26, 26.1]

Here is my div in html:

`<div id="container2" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>`

chart.js

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
      var endpoint = '/api/chart/data';
        var temperature = [];
        var humidity = [];
        var uv = [];
        var light = [];
        var rainfall = [];
        var labels = [];
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: endpoint,
            success: function(data){
                labels = data.labels;
                temperature = data.temperature;
                console.log(temperature);
                setChart(temperature);
            },
            error: function(error_data){
                console.log("error");
                console.log(error_data);
            }
    });


       $(function setChart(temperature){
       console.log(temperature);
           Highcharts.setOptions({
               title: {
                   text: '過去24小時氣溫變化圖'
               },
               chart: {

                   backgroundColor: {
                       linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
                       stops: [
                           [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                           [1, 'rgb(240, 240, 255)']
                           ]
                   },
                   borderWidth: 2,
                   plotBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .9)',
                   plotShadow: true,
                   plotBorderWidth: 1
               }
           });

           var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
               chart: {
                   renderTo: 'container2',
                   type: 'column'
               },

               xAxis: {
                   type: 'datetime'
               },

               series: [{
                   data: temperature,
                   #data: [8,7,5,6,4,2,3,1],
                   pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
                   pointInterval: 3600 * 1000 // one hour
               }]
           });
       });
});
```

The chart can be printed when uncommented the data in series.(`#data: [8,7,5,6,4,2,3,1],`

But when it replaced by `data: temperature,`

Then the some error comes from the following codes:

`setChart(temperature);`

> Uncaught ReferenceError: setChart is not defined at Object.success
>
> at fire [jquery-3.2.1.js:3317](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js)
>
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] [jquery-3.2.1.js:3447](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js)
>
> at done [jquery-3.2.1.js:9272](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js)
>
> at XMLHttpRequest. [jquery-3.2.1.js:9514](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js)

To print out the temperature object was worked at ajax block but failed to print in the setChar()t function.

How can I solved this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `setChart()` function is located in the different scope than the ajax call. Take a look at the example below for corrected demo.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/e37qftg3/